# Read a file saved via FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, html

Good Day,

I'm still new to programming and I'm using FileSaver.js to save a .txt file.

I managed to make the app I'm building saving the file in my "Downloads" folder, but now I hit a wall when I want to read this file.

I understand, for security reasons, we cannot access to the whole computer, but it is the case here ?

I'm using the `FileReader()` method but I'm not able to access the file... I went there https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ and here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files... But unfortunately I don't understand the way to access the file and to read it.

I save the file this way (using FileSaver.js):

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

When it's time to load the file, I do that:

```
var fileToLoad = filename;
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadEvent) {
   console.log("File loaded properly!");
};
content = fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);
```

I would like to put the content of the file into the variable `content`.

If anybody can help me to clarify this... Thank You in advance!

Comment: Are you getting a path to the file on the system when trying to read it? And if so is it relative or full?

Comment: No I'm not. Using the links below, I just have an error message saying the file is not found.

Comment: Looks like @KarenGrigoryan has the answer there for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content = fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);` doesn't return the content,
it simply triggers the asynchronous parsing of the file as text. And only later when the filereader is finished reading the content, you can access it in the onload event object like this:

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
    content = e.target.result; // here is the loaded content;
};
fr.readAsText(fileToLoad);
```